# Are these cracks developing in a brick wall a serious issue?

Tags: repair, foundation, crack, cement, cracks

Been a two month drought, tried to keep up with the clay underneath.  House is on a slope, and it looks like it finally shifted.  There are cracks developing in the garage floor as well, one spot in particular I can feel a slope.

How screwed am I?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the brick is part of a solid masonry wall section, there may be an issue. Typically, most brick nowadays is laid up as a siding, called brick veneer. It is real brick, but only one layer thick, approx. 4" thick. It is laid up with 1" airspace behind it and connected with wall ties to the structural frame wall behind it to keep it stable. This is what I suspect you have. If that is the case, with the few brick that are displaced by settling, can be removed and relaid again.

Just as a mention, it does look like this is a basement wall. There is a chance it could be solid masonry, but I still doubt it is solid in the true sense of the term. This is still probably a veneer against a block wall using the same wall ties to unify the structure, and the block wall is carrying the load.

This all needs to be confirmed, but it is an educated guess.

Answer (score 0):

There is mortor colored caulk. I used it to fill a few small gaps I had. They were similar to the gaps shown. Still looked good 2 years later when I sold it. I doubt these small gaps indicate a foundation problem.